# How to use chcon without selinux?

Tags: selinux

On my system I don't have selinux set up, but I have a removeable disk containing an EXT4 filesystem from a machine that does use selinux. I need to change a file's context on that filesystem. `chcon` fails with "Operation not supported". Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could run a Linux distribution with SELinux enabled, such as Fedora, in a virtual machine. Installing Fedora in a VM takes only a few minutes, not including the download time. Use VM software that supports USB passthrough (such as VirtualBox with the non-open-source extensions) and access the disk directly from the VM.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use `setfattr` to set the `security.selinux` attribute on the file directly, something like:

> setfattr -n security.selinux -v "unconfined_u:object_r:foo_t:s0" /tmp/bar

To see the label, you can use `getfattr -n security.selinux /tmp/bar`